# .net, How to make Redis read from replica and write to master?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

We currently have a service using redis(AWS elasticache), with a couple of replica nodes. For the client we have a .Net-Core aplication using StackExchange.Redis. How can we implement read-only from replica with a Weighted round robin, and write to master node in this case? Is it just a config change?

Are there any good libraries for the task?